# How to create multiple pickerviews programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to create a separate pickerview for each textbox that is selected.  so far the closest I have gotten is having the same pickerview for each of the text boxes that need their own separate list of items to choose from.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var dogBreedPickerArray = ["German Shepherd", "Huskie", "cray cray"]
var catBreedPickerArray = ["savanna", "cheetoh", "bengal"]
var maleFemalePickerArray = ["Male", "Female"]

var dogBreedPicker = UIPickerView()

var dogBreedPicker = UIPickerView()
var catBreedPicker = UIPickerView()
var maleFemalePicker = UIPickerView()

@IBOutlet var dogBreedTextBox: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var catBreedTextBox: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var maleFemaleTextBox: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dogBreedPicker.delegate = self
    dogBreedPicker.dataSource = self
    dogBreedTextBox.inputView = dogBreedPicker

    dogBreedTextBox.delegate = self
                            }
// dog picker functions
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dogBreedPickerArray.count
    }
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    petBreedTextBox.text = dogBreedPickerArray[row]
    }
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return dogBreedPickerArray[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use an if statement within the function, instead of just doing it for the dogBreedPicker.  Like in number of components instead of returning just 1; if dogBreedPicker - return 1, else if catBreedPicker return whatever you want.  Do that for all the func's that you have.  Also for each textfield make sure you use the picker you want.

Comment: use single picker  and load the content on the bases of textfld use if else or switch to load the content on picker use tag to detect what content you have to load on picker and reload the component of picker view .

Answer (score 0):

its just a example may be it help to you 
after selecting any text field asign textfield tag to picker and reload the component.

```
// variable
var heightInch:[Int] = [Int]()
var heightfeet:[Int] = [Int]()
var heightCms:[Int] = [Int]()
delegate methods
  func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if picker.tag == 1{
            return 2
        }else{
            return 1
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if picker.tag == 1{
            switch component {
            case 0:
                return heightfeet.count
            default:
                return heightInch.count
            }

        }else{
            return heightCms.count
        }
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if picker.tag == 1{
            switch component {
            case 0:
                return String(heightfeet[row])
            default:
                return String(heightInch[row])
            }
        }else{
            return String(heightCms[row])
        }
```